# The philosophy of the snob

Tags: ethics, reference-request

Does any philosopher write about snobbery, both in and out of the subject matter itself?

I know people books write about e.g. "stupidity", "bullshit", as it exists both in and out of the subject matter, philosophy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, Matthew Kieran has written a recent paper in *Philosophical Quarterly* based on the problem that it is difficult to know whether one is a snob or not, and how that difficulty might pose a problem for aesthetic justification. The paper is [The vice of snobbery: Aesthetic knowledge, justification and virtue in art appreciation](http://philpapers.org/rec/KIETVO).

That's the one recent paper I know of. To search for other papers on any topic you might search the [PhilPapers database](http://philpapers.org/).

Comment: what about snobbery for something other than art ?